Overplot data in time/date format and function in gnuplot
I use Gnuplot Version 5.4 patchlevel 6. I would like to plot as a function of time (in format "%d %b\n%H:%M:%S") a column in a .csv datafile
2022-02-16T21:22:28.285029000Z.  3.03665
2022-02-16T21:23:28.285035000Z   4.56777
2022-02-16T21:24:28.285041000Z   6.81235
2022-02-16T21:25:28.285047000Z   7.78797
2022-02-16T21:26:28.285052000Z   9.73548
......


I would like to overplot a function of x, for example f(x) = x^2, assuming that I know the conversion factor between the time in the above format (with 1 minute spacing) and the position x: time = x/velocity. I am also trying to define f(x) over a smaller range than the datafile, but I cannot convert the string of date/time into the variable of f(x).
I have
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d %b\n%H:%M:%S"
set xrange ["16-Feb-2022 21:22:28":"16-Feb-2022 23:46:28"]
t1="15-Feb-2022 23:30:28"
t2="16-Feb-2022 07:27:28" 
f(x) = x**2.
f1(x) = f(x/velocity)
f1_t(x) = (x/velocity > t1 && x/velocity < t2) ? f1(x) : 1/0
p "data.txt" u 1:2,  f1_t(x)

I receive "warning: Trailing characters after numeric expression".
I don’t know how to rescale the x-axis and define the offset of x to overplot data and f1_t(x). Does anybody know how to convert a time in date/time format in a way that an analytic function can be overplotted to a datafile?
My attempts, and response of Gnuplot, are described above.

Welcome to StackOverflow! You are dealing with two different date/time formats in your data and in your script. Are both formats given/fixed or could you possibly adjust the one or the other?

In your question, you basically have three different date/time formats. You need to know that time data in gnuplot is handled internally as seconds passed from Jan, 1st 1970 00:00:00 (check help time/date).
With the function strptime() you can convert from a given date/time format into seconds from 1970. So, it might be convenient to do everything in seconds from 1970.
In the example below you have 3 different time formats:

format of input data "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
format you are using in your script "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"
format to be displayed in the graph "%d %b\n%H:%M:%S"

Actually, I wouldn't use the format "%d-%b-%Y" (specifically %b) for handling time data in the script, because then the script might depend on the language settings (check help locale), better use, e.g. "%Y-%m-%d" or the same format as in the input file.
Furthermore, you need to shift the origin of your function, e.g. by t0. Everything is in seconds.
Check the following example as starting point for further variations and optimizations.
Data: SO79158210.dat
2022-02-16T21:22:28.285029000Z   3.03665
2022-02-16T21:23:28.285035000Z   4.56777
2022-02-16T21:24:28.285041000Z   6.81235
2022-02-16T21:25:28.285047000Z   7.78797
2022-02-16T21:26:28.285052000Z   9.73548

Script:
### function on top of time data
reset session

FILE = "SO79158210.dat"

fmtD = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"    # date/time format datafile
fmtS = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"    # date/time format script
fmtG = "%d %b\n%H:%M:%S"      # date/time format graph

# range for data
tD1 = strptime(fmtS, "16-Feb-2022 21:22:15")
tD2 = strptime(fmtS, "16-Feb-2022 21:26:45")

# range for function
tF1 = strptime(fmtS, "16-Feb-2022 21:23:00")
tF2 = strptime(fmtS, "16-Feb-2022 21:25:45")
t0  = strptime(fmtS, "16-Feb-2022 21:24:11")   # zero for function

set xrange [tD1:tD2]
set format x fmtG timedate
set key top left
set sample 21

factor = 0.03     # units per sec
f(t)   = ((t-t0)*factor)**2

plot FILE u (timecolumn(1,fmtD)):2 w lp pt 7 ti "Data", \
     [t=tF1:tF2] f(t) w lp ti "f(t)"
### end of script

Result:


Thank you very much! That was very helpful. The date/time format in datafile and script were different because I copied from a different script version and did not check, apologies.

@Fred ok, glad to hear. So, question answered? Then please check the checkmark at the top left of the answer indicating that your problem is solved.
